# Start X and browser within openbox on start

Tags: xorg, openbox

I have a virtualbox setup and I am logged in via ssh

```
/opt/kiosk.sh

#!/bin/bash
xset -dpms
xset s off
openbox-session &
start-pulseaudio-x11

chromium-browser --kiosk --no-first-run  'http://thepcspy.com'


root@t3000:~# startx /etc/X11/Xsession /opt/kiosk.sh --


X.Org X Server 1.19.6
Release Date: 2017-12-20
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 4.4.0-119-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux t3000 4.15.0-33-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 15 16:00:05 UTC 2018 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-33-generic  root=UUID=12ef906c-b7ad-474d-8cbb-e65263737416 ro splash quiet
Build Date: 13 April 2018  08:07:36PM
xorg-server 2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
   (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Mon Sep 10 09:54:47 2018
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
pci id for fd 14: 80ee:beef, driver (null)
EGL_MESA_drm_image required.
xinit: connection to X server lost

waiting for X server to shut down (II) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
```

[/var/log/Xorg.0.log](https://pastebin.com/cwnt7QE1)

```
sudo -u tmil startx /etc/X11/Xsession /opt/kiosk.sh --

X.Org X Server 1.19.6
Release Date: 2017-12-20
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 4.4.0-119-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux t3000 4.15.0-33-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 15 16:00:05 UTC 2018 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-33-generic root=UUID=12ef906c-b7ad-474d-8cbb-e65263737416 ro splash quiet
Build Date: 13 April 2018  08:07:36PM
xorg-server 2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
  Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
  to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
  (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
  (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/home/tmil/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log", Time: Mon Sep 10 09:56:58 2018
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
(EE) 
Fatal server error:
(EE) parse_vt_settings: Cannot open /dev/tty0 (Permission denied)
(EE) 
(EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
   at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
(EE) Please also check the log file at "/home/tmil/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
(EE) 
(EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
xinit: server error
Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console
```

[/home/tmil/.local/shared/xorg/Xorg.0.log](https://pastebin.com/tRvwawu6)

If I log in from the virtual box window, directly, with the »kiosk user« credentials and run:

```
 startx /etc/X11/Xsession /opt/kiosk.sh --
```

Everything is just running. What's the catch here??

Comment: "_Cannot open /dev/tty0 (**Permission denied**)_"

Comment: Yeah, that seams to be reason why it doesn't start, but how can I run/configure the whole thing such that it has the permission ? Running: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure x11-common` to enable that does not work on this `ubuntu 18.04`. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1073862/configure-x-to-be-started-by-non-root-user